# why some IOException is thrown out from library code?

Tags: java

I am using a third party library code, calling just one method. The method is declared to throw ZZException, however when running in the real environment, we found this method throwed out IOExceoption sometime.

```
public void TestMethod() throws ZZException
```

I am wondering why there is no decalrtion for IOException thrown? If not declaring throw IOException, can IOException being throwed out?

BTW, ZZException is  subclass of RuntimeException

Comment: Are you sure that what is thrown is an IOException and not a ZZException caused by an IOException (which is legal and the recommended way to do it)?

Comment: I am sure it is IOException get thrown out.

Comment: is ZZException a subclass of IOException? If so, catching an IOException will also catch a ZZException. Could that be what's happening?

Comment: Also, is java.io.IOException from the SDK, or maybe the developer has created their own IOException making it a runtime exception. You can check it by catching the IOException. If you can only catch it via Exception and/or inherits from the runtime error, it would be a strong signal this is what they did, and a really bad idea.

Comment: @Luis Good thinking, though such a developer would deserve a stern glare.

Comment: Everything would clear up if you just posted the stack trace by removing sensitive information...

Comment: @yshavit In a way, it scares me I can think something so convoluted.

Comment: @Luis If we want to get *really* convoluted, you can also use generics + raw types to write Java code that will happily compile and let you throw checked exceptions without declaring them. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thsi might be an Error in the Library code or and other error in using the library, the best way to know is to report this to the developer including some code and see his answer.

Comment: why there is such error. Java cannot compile if this error happened?

Comment: Well any failed or interrupted I/O operations will cause an IOException, this has nothing to do with compiling, even if your code is valid at runtime it can still happen that something goes wrong and an Exception is thrown, if this exception is not caught by mistake it will be shown on a higher level.

Comment: @user705414: take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/putItTogether.html in this example if the catch statement wouldnt catch an IOException this would be thrown like in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `ZZException` is the superclass of `IOException`, `IOException` can't be thrown out in place of `ZZException`. The concept of exception chaining allows you to specify a "cause" for a given exception. Are you sure you are not seeing `IOException` in the stack trace as a "cause" for the original `ZZException`? It would help if you could show us the stack trace you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Unless ZZException is a subclass of IOException the method as documented cannot throw an IOException. Most likely the documentation is wrong/outdated. What happens when you compile against the class? Does the compiler think it can throw an IOException?

Another explanation would be that it does not get thrown at all, but it just looks that way in the log file, because the code logs a stacktrace, or because it throws a ZZException that wraps an IOException (as its cause).

Comment: Superclass or parent, not subclass.

Comment: If ZZException extends IOException, then the method can throw an IOException (namely ZZException), just not *any* IOException.